# Programmatically changing the 'Activities I am following' under Newsfeed Settings

Tags: activity-feed

is it possible to programatically select/deselect activities I am following on the news feed preferences page under MySites? I want to be able switch on/off notifications for both custom events and those provided by Sharepoint 2010 out-of-the-box.

Answer (score 1):

you may want to check "Using Activity Feeds with Object Model" topic under SharePoint SDK: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff426881.aspx

Below you can find example that will list current user 'Activities I'm following' settings.

```
string currentSite = "http://URL goes here";
using (SPSite aSite = new SPSite(currentSite))
{
    SPServiceContext currentContext = SPServiceContext.GetContext(aSite);
    UserProfileManager userProfMan = new UserProfileManager(currentContext);
    string userName = Environment.UserDomainName + "\\" + Environment.UserName;
    UserProfile currentUser = userProfMan.GetUserProfile(userName);
    ActivityManager activityMan = new ActivityManager(currentUser, currentContext);
    foreach (ActivityType activityType in activityMan.ActivityTypes)
    {
         Console.WriteLine(activityType.ActivityTypeName + " " + activityType.ActivityTypeId + " " 
         + (activityMan.ActivityPreferences[activityType.ActivityTypeId] != null ? "true" : "false"));
     }
}
```

Look at the 'How to: Get Events for Users' code sample (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff426883(v=office.14).aspx) on how to modify 'Activities I'm following' preferences.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this power shell script

```
#Load the SharePoint snap-in
Add-PsSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell;

#Load the SharePoint assemblies
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.Office.Server");
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles");

#Specify the MySite URL
$MySiteUrl = "http://santosh-pc:39242/";

#Get the server context for the profile manager
$site = Get-SPSite $MySiteUrl;
$ServerContext = Get-SPServiceContext $site;
$UPManager = new-object Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.UserProfileManager($ServerContext);

#Count variables
$ucount = 0;

$enumProfiles = $UPManager.GetEnumerator();
"Total User Profiles available:" + $UPManager.Count
$count=0;

#Loop through the profile entries and update the property
#Recieve Instant Notifications - NGAllowMetaEmail (bool)
#24 Hour Digest Email - NGReceiveDigestEmail (bool)
#RSS NewsFeed Email - NGAllowRssEmail (bool)
#SharePoint Notification emails - SPS-EmailOptin (int)
#This field has 3 values one for each email type

foreach ($oUser in $enumProfiles)
{
    $count = $count + 1;
    $u = $oUser.Item("Accountname");
    Write-Output "($count):  Setting values for $u";

    $oUser["NGAllowMetaEmail"].Value = $false;
    $oUser["NGReceiveDigestEmail"].Value = $false;
    $oUser["NGAllowRssEmail"].Value = $false;
    $oUser["SPS-EmailOptin"].Value = 111; 

    $oUser.Commit();
} 

#Dispose of site object
$site.Dispose();
```